# Supporting multi languages and screen sizes

Tags: android, localization, screen-size

I am creating an application which i try to support multiple languages. I put my english text in

```
 values/strings.xml
```

French text to

```
 values-fr/strings.xml
```

Now , i want to support multiple screens , too. I have these folders

```
 values-normal-ldpi
 values-normal-mdpi
 values-large
 values-xlarge
 values
```

If user is French , and screen is large. it always choose strings from values-fr but dimens from values folder.. Should i have all of these values folder for french too (like values-fr-normal-ldpi etc. )? Is there any other way

Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. You just need to define the dimension inside each density folder, and Android will use the dimension based on device's screen density AND text based on selected language.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple screen support you need to create 4 different folder in res>layout folder of android structure

layout-hdpi 
layout-mdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-ldpi
layout-xxhdpi

each folder contains layout files of there respective dimensions and name of these files are same throug out all folders

also you need to create 
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi and so on folder for different revolution images with same name

so smartly OS can detect resoltuion of device and from matching folder it shows images on your device

follow this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

about localisation your way is correct